# How do I map the stream filter function of tweepy with the thread pool?

Tags: python, tweepy

Using the library:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
```

I am streaming tweets and then processing them as follows:

```
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
httpsCheck = 'https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+'
httpCheck = 'http?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+'

def on_status(self, status):
    if status.retweeted:
        return
    tweetText = status.text.encode('utf8')
    created_at = status.created_at
    id = status.id
    if (re.findall(self.httpCheck, tweetText) or re.findall(self.httpsCheck, tweetText)):
        return
    if (re.search('[a-zA-Z]', tweetText)):
        response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
            text=tweetText,
            features=Features(
                entities=EntitiesOptions(
                    emotion=True,
                    sentiment=True,
                    limit=2),
                keywords=KeywordsOptions(
                    emotion=True,
                    sentiment=True,
                    limit=2)),
            language='en'
            )
        response["tweet"] = tweetText
        response["id"] = id
        response["created_at"] = created_at
        with open('#LFCROMA-SF2.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            for key, value in response.items():
                writer.writerow([key, value])

def on_error(self, status_code):
    if status_code == 420:
        return False
```

Now, I want to use multi-threading in order to increase my speed using `pool`

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(settingsTwitter.TWITTER_APP_KEY, settingsTwitter.TWITTER_APP_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(settingsTwitter.TWITTER_KEY, settingsTwitter.TWITTER_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
stream_listener = StreamListener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream_listener)
pool = ThreadPool(4)
pool.map(stream.filter, languages=["en"], track=["#LFC"])
```

By doing so, I am getting an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "atomic.py", line 66, in
>   
>       pool.map(stream.filter, languages=["en"], track=["#LFC"]) TypeError: map() got an unexpected keyword argument 'languages'

I am unable to figure out a way to call this function in `pool.map()`

The purpose is to stream tweets, apply some heavy processing and then save the results. There is a bottleneck as streaming >> processing in terms of speed. Which is why I want to stream tweets in a multithreaded approach.

Comment: Which `Threadpool` ? Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: @Prateek I have edited the question. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to have this sorted out is:

- Stream tweets seperately and dont use threading on them.
- Write a function which would read the tweets and then send it for processing(Watson NLU processing in this case)
- The reading of the tweets from the file in `tail -f` manner in a parallel manner(multi threading) will ensure that there is no processing bottleneck.

To understand this with an eg:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import csv
import json
import settingsWatson
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
from watson_developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding_v1 import Features, EntitiesOptions, KeywordsOptions, CategoriesOptions
import os
import time
import settingsTwitter
import tweepy
import datetime
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
  username=settingsWatson.username,
  password=settingsWatson.password,
  version='2018-03-16')

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
  tweet = {}
  httpsCheck = 'https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+'
  httpCheck = 'http?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+'
  idSelf = 0
  fieldNames = ['tweet', 'sequence', 'created_at', 'id']

  def on_status(self, status):
    if status.retweeted:
      return
    tweetText = status.text.encode('utf8')
    created_at = status.created_at
    id = status.id
    if (re.findall(self.httpCheck, tweetText) or re.findall(self.httpsCheck, tweetText)):
      return
    if (re.search('[a-zA-Z]', tweetText)):
      self.idSelf += 1
      self.tweet["tweet"] = tweetText
      self.tweet["id"] = id
      self.tweet["sequence"] = self.idSelf
      self.tweet["created_at"] = created_at
      with open('#ELCLASICO-2018-05-07.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        #json.dump(self.tweet, json_file, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default = str)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, self.tweet.keys())
        #for key, value in self.tweet.items():
        #a = [self.tweet]
        #print a[0]['tweet']
        writer.writerow(self.tweet)

  def on_error(self, status_code):
    if status_code == 420:
      return False

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(settingsTwitter.TWITTER_APP_KEY, settingsTwitter.TWITTER_APP_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(settingsTwitter.TWITTER_KEY, settingsTwitter.TWITTER_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
print "Twitter API Authentication is successful!"
stream_listener = StreamListener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream_listener)
print "Streaming begins!"

def startStream():
  while True:
    try:
      stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream_listener)
      stream.filter(languages=["en"], track=["#ElClasico"])
    except:
      continue

startStream()
```

The above code is used to stream tweets with certain conditions and then save them in a CSV file.

However, this was never an issue. The issue was in my "atomic" approach. I should have avoided the bottleneck not by bringing the whole procedure(stream, process, save) in one but by distributed computing approach(stream is one task, process is another). Note, that this method fails as well(since the processing can never match the speed of the stream). In order to overcome this, I applied multithreading in a distributed fashion:

- Stream tweets
- Save tweets
  [this (below) is the point from where multithreading approach starts]
- Read the tweets in tail -f manner
- Send them to Watson for processing
- Perform Data File Handling and stuff

This is the code for processing stuff:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import csv
import json
import settingsWatson
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
from watson_developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding_v1 import Features, EntitiesOptions, KeywordsOptions, CategoriesOptions
import os
import time
import settingsTwitter
import tweepy
import datetime
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
    username=settingsWatson.username,
    password=settingsWatson.password,
    version='2018-03-16')

class FileTailer(object):

    def __init__(self, file, delay=1):
        self.file = file
        self.delay = delay

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            where = self.file.tell()
            line = self.file.readline()
            if line and line.endswith('\n'): # only emit full lines
                yield line
                #response = self.naturalLanguageProcessing(line)
            else:
                print "Waiting for new line"
                # for a partial line, pause and back up
                time.sleep(self.delay)       # ...not actually a recommended approach.
                self.file.seek(where)


class watson:

  entityDict = {"Messi":["Lionel Messi", "Leo", "Messi"], "Ronaldo":["Cristiano Ronaldo", "Cristiano", "Ronaldo"], "Iniesta":["Andres Iniesta", "Iniesta"], "Barcelona":["Barca", "Barcelona", "FC Barcelona", "#FCBarcelona"], "Real Madrid":["Real Madrid", "Madrid", "#RMA", "#RealMadrid"]}
  date = "2018-05-06"

  def createFiles(self):
    for entity in self.entityDict:
      fileName = str(entity) + "-" + str(self.date) + ".csv"
      print fileName
      with open(fileName, 'wb') as myFile:
        wr = csv.writer(myFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    print "This is the entity defined list:"
    print self.entityDict
    for i in self.entityDict:
      for j in self.entityDict[i]:
        print j

  def naturalLanguageProcessing(self,tweetText):
    print "NLP is called with this text: " + tweetText
    try:
      response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
        text=tweetText,
        features=Features(
          entities=EntitiesOptions(
            emotion=True,
            sentiment=True,
            limit=2),
          keywords=KeywordsOptions(
            emotion=True,
            sentiment=True,
            limit=2)),
        language='en'
        )
      response["tweet"] = tweetText
      self.saveResults(response)
    except:
      print "Error occured. Sleeping for one"
      time.sleep(1)
      return None

  def saveResults(self, response):
    print "Saving the results"
    entitiesTweet = response["entities"]
    print "Printing entitiesTweet"
    print entitiesTweet
    for entity in entitiesTweet:
      try:
        for i in self.entityDict:
          for j in self.entityDict[i]:
            if(j == entity["text"]):
              fileName = str(self.entityDict[i]) + "-" + str(self.date) + ".csv"
              with open(fileName, 'a') as myFile:
                wr = csv.writer(myFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                entity["tweet"] = response["tweet"]
                wr.writerow([entity])
      except Exception as e:
        print (e)

          #entityToBeInserted = entity
          #entityToBeInserted["tweet"] = response["tweet"]
          #fileName = str(entityItem) + "-" + str(date) + ".csv"
          #with open(fileName, 'a') as myFile:
            #wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            #wr.writerow([entityToBeInserted])
    with open('#ELCLASICO-2018-05-07-Watson.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
      writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
      writer.writerow([response])


  #def saveEntityResults(self, entities, date):



def initiator(farzi):
  csv_reader = csv.reader(FileTailer(open('#ELCLASICO-2018-05-07.csv')))
  ob = watson()
  for row in csv_reader:
    tweet = row[1]
    ob.naturalLanguageProcessing(tweet)

pool = ThreadPool(4) 
farzi = "farzi"
pool.map(initiator, farzi)
```

Answer (score 1):

***Warning :*** `from multiprocessing.pool import Pool as ThreadPool` will override pool.ThreadPool method.

So use it as `from multiprocessing.pool import Pool`

```
>>>help(Pool.map)
Help on function map in module multiprocessing.pool:
map(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None)
    Apply `func` to each element in `iterable`, collecting the results
    in a list that is returned.
```

Please see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html)

You should pass function and an instance of iterable object for this to work.

So remove `languages = ['en']` since map function does not have languages parameter

Instead try

```
pool.map(function, <a_list you want to pass to function> )
```

Coming to `tweepy`

After `Stream` please just filter the tweets as in documentation

`stream.filter(languages=['en'], track=["#LFC"])`

> You do not need to call `pool.map` function here.

`stream.filter` will give you result just fine.

In order to call your custom stream listener change `stream_listener = StreamListener()` to

```
stream_listener = CustomStreamListener()
```

You can call `pool.map` as below :

```
with Pool(4) as p:
    p.map(stream.filter(languages=['en'], track=["#LFC"]))
```

#### But

Twitter API comes with rate limit and access limit. If you are using standard version you will get the below error.

> An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
>   current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

This is because you are creating threads and trying to call same API multiple times,
since you single access token this is prohibited.

---

In case you multiple API access accounts then you would do the below:

```
auth_list = [auth1,auth2,auth3,auth4] #.... if more
with Pool(4) as p:
    p.map(stream.filter(languages=['en'], track=["#LFC"]),auth_list)
```

Please check if enterprise edition does not have such [limitations](https://developer.twitter.com/en/apply-for-access)

---

**Note :** To avoid being blocked use `wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True`.
    `api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)`

Comment: I got an error:
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'int' and 'list'**
Changes:
`pool.map(stream.filter, ['en'], ['#LFC'])`

Comment: it wont take [#LFC] , I have updated answer , please check

Comment: Do you know, if I write `t = stream.filter(languages=['en'], track=["#LFC"])` it will call the on_status function which would be then calling the desired function without threading? Also, the function you have written in pool.map() is the stream.filter function itself.

Comment: https://github.com/avisrivastava254084/bubble-avi/blob/master/atomic.py
This is the complete code. 
1. I create an instance of StreamListener
2. I create a `stream` variable
3. I call the stream.filter function with the params

Comment: Adding the class. My bad.

Comment: Yes, not an error but you are not getting what I am trying to say. I have customised the on_status function and I need to use it in a multi-threaded way. This function is called with the statement: `stream.filter, languages=["en"], track=["#LFC"]`

Comment: I am trying to stream tweets and send it to a blackbox for processing. Now, I want this to be atomic i.e. stream a tweet, process it and save it. Explains why I have customised the on_status function. Now, I can use the stream.filter statement only once but I want to call it via pool.map so that I have multi threading and hence the speed increases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, upvoted because I learnt a lot from this exhaustive research of yours. However, I have posted an answer, just now, which seems to solve the issues of my classmates(mine). Thanks, again!